# ng test error, No binary for Chrome browser on your platform. Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I started the unit testing tutorial for angular, but upon doing the ng test, I am getting error saying

06 10 2022 22:02:54.887:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.

Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.

I search the few thing that does not seem to help. I am using the fedora 36 for development work.
can anyone assist me here ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently flatpak app does not bode well due to sandboxing, download the rpm version from chrome site. It resolved my issue.